# Replacing pandas index with another pandas index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rename a pandas index column with another pandas index value. The code is as follows:

```
for (b,c) in zip(pearson.index, a['Company Name']):
    print(pearson.index.rename(columns={'b': 'c'}))
```

If i just `print(b, c)` it works fine but when i try to execute the code above, it give the following error:

```
TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

Could you please just explain to me what does this error mean and why the code is not working?

Comment: What does your `pearson` frame and `a` frame look like and what are you expecting the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why do you use a `for` loop while renaming the index. the error means the attribute `rename()` doesn't have `columns` as an argument.  If you instead really want to rename the index, you can use `name` as argument. Here is an example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df.index.rename(name='index', inplace=True)
```

Gives you,

```sh
     A  B
index       
0    1  4
1    2  5
2    3  6
```